# Is Relative automation broken in 10.6.2?

Tags: logic-pro

Long-time Logic user here but I've never gotten Relative automation to work on track Volume.

I know the workarounds: I've always had to use the separate Gain plugin workaround to allow me to automate volume levels on a track and then later still be able to adjust overall track level balance during mixing.

But I'm sick of that because unless I'm gravely mistaken, this is what the role of Relative Volume automation should be: the Relative automation track modulate the main Volume automation. And if you have NO main (absolute) volume automation, the Relative automation should be adjusting the (un-automated) track's master volume such that you should be able to adjust the main volume fader and still see the results of your relative automation working on the main track volume.

In practice however this is not the case. Try it - record a track, then enable automation and choose Relative Volume (+-). Draw a simple automation curve from min to max and back down again. Play your track - you'll hear the volume go from min to max. Now, adjust the main volume slider for that track - turn it all the way down to -inf dB. Play the track. You shouldn't be able to hear your track at all, and yet, you do and nothing has changed from the previous. Now slam that fader to max (+6dB). No difference? Yeah that's just not right.

Have I completely missed the point here? If I have, please explain the purpose of Relative Volume automation because the logic manual's description matches my expected behaviour described above.

Comment: I'm not a Logic user, but to my mind, if you have no automation you have nothing for it to be relative **to**. I'd at least think you would have to set one initial value at the head of the track.

Comment: @Tetsujin that's a good thought, but doesn't seem to be the case here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question here. **Yes, it is broken**. It actually *works* as intended but, inexplicably, not in real-time. While playing back your track with Relative volume automation, adjusting the main volume slider or automation has no audible effect, until.....

When you STOP playback you will immediately hear your volume jump to whatever level you have set it to with the main fader. When you restart playback, the relative automation does in fact affect the main track volume relative to where you last set the fader. This works equally on the main Volume automation track (not relative) - you can slide your main automation curve up and down and, while you won't hear it in real time, once you stop and start your relative automation will influence your main volume.

This works equally for Trim and for Relative mode.

Yet another of those quirks of Logic you just have to swallow because it's one heck of a lot of DAW packed into a $300 package.